# Compile Error: DML operation DELETE not allowed on User

Tags: salesforce

i write apex class for Delete the user records but i got error that error shows like this

Error: Compile Error: DML operation DELETE not allowed on User at line 28 column 7
how to solve this error please let me know.

Answer (score 9):

User object is not deletable, to "delete" a user and retrieve a license to use on another user you have to disable the user by setting `isActive` to false. This will cause its license to go back to the pool.